# I don't have any idea about how to execute this Python script (program)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, execution

Hi please i want your help I don't know how to execute this python script or run i wrote attack() but there is no result , if any one can help and thak you so much .

and please can you check if it's coorrect ( syntax ) .

```
def attack():

while 1:
    X = list(
            map(float_input,[
                "WHAT IS TARGET SHIP LENGTH IN FEET?\n",
                "WHAT IS TARGET SHIP BEAM IN FEET?\n",
                "WHAT IS TARGET SHIP SPEED IN KNOTS?\n",
                "WHAT IS RANGE TARGET TO SUB IN YARDS?\n",
                "WHAT IS ASPECT ANGLE (ANGLE ON THE TARGET BOW) IN DEGREES?\n",
                "HOW MANY TORPEDOS IN A SALVO?\n",
                "WHAT IS THE COVERAGE FACTOR? ( TORPEDO SPREAD + TARGET SHIP LENGTH)\n",
                "WHAT IS TORPEDO SPEED IN KNOTS?\n",
                "WHAT IS TORPEDO MAXIMUM RANGE IN YARDS?\n",
            ]))

    print("YOUR ANSWERS IN ORDER WERE ")
    print(' '.join(vector))
    if input("ARE THEY OK? YES/NO\n")=="YES":
        break
    else:
        print('\n'*5)

SW = list(
            map(yes_no_input,[
                    "DO YOU WANT TRACK PROBABILITIES DISPLAYED? YES/NO\n",
                    "DO YOU WANT TRACK ANGLE, RUN DISTANCE, RUN TIME, EFFECTIVE LENGTH, AND TL DISPLAYED? YES/NO\n",
                    "DO YOU WANT HITS DISPLAYED? YES/NO\n"
                ]))

while 1:
    print("IF YOU HAVE A VULNERABILITY VECTOR I’’LL COMPUTE EXPECTED LOSSES.")
    VUL = input("INPUT THE VECTOR STARTING WITH PROB OF LOSS GIVEN ONE HIT,PROB OF LOSS GIVEN TWO HITS, ...ETC. IF AVAILABLE. OTHERWISE HIT THE RETURN.\n")

    try:
        VUL = 0 if not VUL else (map(float, VUL.split()) if ' ' in VUL else [float(VUL)])
        SW.append(bool(VUL))
        break
    
    except:
        print('Please insert floats or integers in vectors')
```

Comment: The indentation looks wrong -- is all of that code supposed to be inside the `attack()` function definition?

Comment: so how can i fix it

Comment: select, hit Tab

Comment: i didn't got you

Comment: That's clear, yes.  :)  Indentation is such a fundamental thing in Python that it doesn't seem productive to try to help you get this code to work.  I suggest starting with a basic Python tutorial and writing a few of your own simple programs before trying to modify someone else's.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: i want just to know how to run it not modify it

Comment: The program as written is broken -- you can't run it without first fixing it, and you'll need to learn some Python to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Save the file with a name (let "firstpython.py") and extension should be ".py"

**Second:** Open the command prompt/terminal then write ,

```
python "firstpython.py"
```

If the file has no error it will run and display the desired result else, it will show the error in the file(most probably the indentation error)

Answer (score 0):

OK there are 2 things that im aware of wrong in your program, one is **your syntax** and another is **why it wont run**

*Disclaimer: somethings you might already know, but I'll say it just in case*

**THE SYNTAX ERROR:**

The syntax of a function should ideally look like this

```
def {function name}():
   code
```

the indent is important as it is nessesary for python to tell which code is inside the function

your program should be edited to something like:

```
def attack():
    while 1:
        X = list(
            map(float_input, [
                "WHAT IS TARGET SHIP LENGTH IN FEET?\n",
                "WHAT IS TARGET SHIP BEAM IN FEET?\n",
                "WHAT IS TARGET SHIP SPEED IN KNOTS?\n",
                "WHAT IS RANGE TARGET TO SUB IN YARDS?\n",
                "WHAT IS ASPECT ANGLE (ANGLE ON THE TARGET BOW) IN DEGREES?\n",
                "HOW MANY TORPEDOS IN A SALVO?\n",
                "WHAT IS THE COVERAGE FACTOR? ( TORPEDO SPREAD + TARGET SHIP LENGTH)\n",
                "WHAT IS TORPEDO SPEED IN KNOTS?\n",
                "WHAT IS TORPEDO MAXIMUM RANGE IN YARDS?\n",
            ]))
    
        print("YOUR ANSWERS IN ORDER WERE ")
        print(' '.join(vector))
        if input("ARE THEY OK? YES/NO\n") == "YES":
            break
        else:
            print('\n' * 5)
    
    SW = list(
        map(yes_no_input, [
            "DO YOU WANT TRACK PROBABILITIES DISPLAYED? YES/NO\n",
            "DO YOU WANT TRACK ANGLE, RUN DISTANCE, RUN TIME, EFFECTIVE LENGTH, AND TL DISPLAYED? YES/NO\n",
            "DO YOU WANT HITS DISPLAYED? YES/NO\n"
        ]))
    
    while 1:
        print("IF YOU HAVE A VULNERABILITY VECTOR I’’LL COMPUTE EXPECTED LOSSES.")
        VUL = input(
            "INPUT THE VECTOR STARTING WITH PROB OF LOSS GIVEN ONE HIT,PROB OF LOSS GIVEN TWO HITS, ...ETC. IF AVAILABLE. OTHERWISE HIT THE RETURN.\n")
    
        try:
            VUL = 0 if not VUL else (map(float, VUL.split()) if ' ' in VUL else [float(VUL)])
            SW.append(bool(VUL))
            break
    
        except:
            print('Please insert floats or integers in vectors')
```

That solves the indentation, the next problem is why it is not running

**WHY IT IS NOT RUNNING:**

**Possibility number 1.**
in python, a function doesnt run unless called, so at the end of your code add a
`attack()`
at the end of your code

**Possibility number 2.**
if this is just a snippet of code, and you call `attack()` in another portion of the code, it is because you haven't made it output anything, or return anything, so it has no way of showing that it has ran, even though it did. If the target of the code is to change global variables, then before using the variables, under your function name add the global variables you want changed. If you havent declared it globally, it might not work, so out of every scope, you have to define the variable to none at the top of the code screen. If you define variables in your function, it wont exist outside of it. I reccomend reading this article: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Thank you for reading this, hope it helped you in any way!